# What is different about these two pairs of strings that makes this sed script with one and not the other?

Tags: string, sed, scripting, multiline

This question is related to this other question I asked earlier today:
[Find and replace text with all-inclusive wild card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32165125/find-and-replace-text-with-all-inclusive-wild-card/32165645#32165645)

I have a text file like this

```
I want= to keep this
        This is some <text> I want to keep <and "something" in tags that I" want to keep> aff FOO1 WebServices and some more "text" that" should "</be> </deleted>
        <this is stuff in tags I want=to begone> and other text I want gone too. </this is stuff in tags I want to begone> 
       A novice programmer walked into a "BAR2" descript keepthis
        and this even more text, let's keep it
    <I actually want this>
    and this= too.`
```

when I use `sed -f script.sed file.txt` to run this script:

```
# Check for "aff"
/\baff\b/    {   
# Define a label "a"
:a  
# If the line does not contain "desc"
/\bdesc\b/!{
# Get the next line of input and append
    # it to the pattern buffer
    N
    # Branch back to label "a"
    ba
}   
# Replace everything between aff and desc
s/\(\baff\)\b.*\b\(desc\b\)/\1TEST DATA\2/
}
```

I get this as my output:

```
       I want= to keep this
        This is some <text> I want to keep <and "something" in tags that I" want to keep> aff FOO1 WebServices and some more "text" that" should "</be> </deleted>
        <this is stuff in tags I want=to begone> and other text I want gone too. </this is stuff in tags I want to begone> 
       A novice programmer walked into a "BAR2" descript keepthis
        and this even more text, let's keep it
    <I actually want this>
    and this= too.
```

However, by simply changing the search strings from `aff` and `desc` to `FOO1` and `BAR2`:

```
   # Check for "FOO1"
/\bFOO1\b/    {   
# Define a label "a"
:a  
# If the line does not contain "BAR2"
/\bBAR2\b/!{
# Get the next line of input and append
    # it to the pattern buffer
    N
    # Branch back to label "a"
    ba
}   
# Replace everything between FOO1 and BAR2
s/\(\bFOO1\)\b.*\b\(BAR2\b\)/\1TEST DATA\2/
}
```

gives the expected output:

```
I want= to keep this
This is some <text> I want to keep <and "something" in tags that I" want to keep> aff FOO1TEST DATABAR2" descript keepthis
    and this even more text, let's keep it
<I actually want this>
and this= too.`
```

I am completely stumped about what is going on here. Why should searching between `FOO1` and `BAR2` work differently from the exact same script with `aff` and `desc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The end marker should be `\bdesc` instead of `\bdesc\b`.

Note the `\b` in the pattern, it matches a [*word boundary*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). Your above text contains the word *description*, but not *desc*.

Your previous question made me assume that you want that. If you don't care about word boundaries, remove the `\b` escape sequences completely.

Comment: OK, that takes care of that.. and words are defined by white spaces, not the the presence of non-word characters? I'm pretty sure I tried matching the whole words the first few times I tried it, but if something like `thistext="thattext"` would be treated as one word (and `thistext` would not be found), then I think that is where I went wrong (although also without understanding what the `\b`'s were doing anyway).

Comment: Indeed, sometimes word boundaries don't fit to parse data were meaningful terms are concatenated by *word* characters.